# How can I use the UUID API?

Tags: 8, entities, features

I am aware that the question is (almost) a duplicate of the following question [#21991](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21991/is-there-any-documentation-for-the-uuid-module), which has been posted back in 2012. But that question is NOT related to Drupal 8, where UUID is in core.

References:

- [Drupal 8 Core API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8/search/UUID)
- [Drupal 8 Core Module Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1283408)

The Drupal 8 Core Module Documentation does not list UUID.

I wonder if I could leverage Drupal 8's core UUID module to migrate and map relational data imported from a different environment, which has unique keys generated by Firebase.

Update:

It has been kindly pointed out that UUID is not a module.

It seems to make UUID records per default for entities (aka nodes) and apparently can be used to map entity references.

Can I make use of this when I introduce external data, that already has unique IDs?
So I have the "node" IDs and can map with the UUIDs?

Update based on further comments:

The goal is to use UUID with entities and the REST module.
Respectively, it seems sensible to do so when importing external relational data, that already has unique IDs.

I just try to understand how UUID works, what it can do and what not, how I can generate and validate UUID's, what I need to be aware of, if I introduce external ID's.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume what you want to know is how to generate a UUID in Drupal 8, because there's really not much else that you can do ;)

Entities all have an UUID automatically, so if you store your data as a config or content entity, you just have to define the uuid entity key.

To generate a UUID yourself, you need the uuid service:

```
$uuid = \Drupal::service('uuid');
$uuid->generate();
$uuid->isValid($uuid_to_validate);
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand so far, that they are generated automatically. So you suggest that I have to introduce the external UUID logic via the service you mentioned? But that would be for generation. Can I also save an entity with a given UUID?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried it yet. That's why I was originally asking for a documentation, so I can do some research.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Note that I'm talking about a (Symfony) Dependency injection service, not a web service. Yes, you can save entities with your own UUID if you already have one, just pass it to YourEntity::create() as an initial value.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you know where I can get more information about this, besides the API? Because it's somewhat difficult to figure out the whole picture just looking at the API.

Comment: Not sure which picture you mean as it is still not clear to me what you are trying to do. There really is nothing more to say about the UUID component/service itself, it does nothing but generate and validate UUID's. If that does not answer your question, then maybe you asked the wrong question :) Try to ask exactly what you are trying to achieve, possibly as a new question. Because it might be that your question isn't so much about UUID as it is about how entity or maybe the REST module are using UUID's. Also, hi fellow Swiss person :)

Comment: Ok... My ignorance stems from the fact that there is "sparse documentation" for this apparently powerful tool, at least what came to my attention so far. I guess asking for more resources is a valid question (No offense meant to you nor the creators). Yes, the goal is to use it with entities and the REST module. I just try to understand how UUID works, what it can do and what not. Your comment helped me a lot to understand it better. Thank you, fellow Swiss person ;)

Comment: Btw, if no one else can offer a link to some blog or documentation, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Well, that is kind of my point. The UUID service is *not* "a powerful tool". It is very, very simple. It generates UUIDs, that's all it does and will ever do. Serialization uses UUID's for references, but how that stuff works has very little to do with UUID other than it uses them as unique identifiers. So if you want to know more about that, then ask a specific question about that, what you want to do exactly, and I can try to answer that.

Comment: Should the code be `$uuid_to_validate = $uuid->generate();`

Answer (score 9):

To generate uuid with drush:

```
drush php-eval "echo \Drupal::service('uuid')->generate();"
```